# Forbiddening access for users but not ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-403

I got a folder called `'core'` inside my website files.

The core folder include PHP files and function that I don't want users to access, so I forbade it by changing folder Permissions to 700.

The problem is, that this folder include files that are in use with `ajax`, that I don't want the user to access, but I wan't `ajax` to access.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

make htaccess file and save that you may hope to prevent folder. type the code below in your text editor

```
options -Indexes
```

and save it with no name. but make it extention when you save it as  `.htaccess`

Comment: I don't want user to gain permission only to the **files** inside of **core**

Answer (score 0):

What i think you need is something like this: create new file .htaccess in that folder and add this line

```
<Files ~ "^.*">
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "^index\.php|css|js|.*\.png|.*\.jpg|.*\.gif">
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

The user cannot access the folder but your ajax and scripts will be able to use the core folder for getting files or anything. Also your question is not very clear and it suggests that you don't really know how file permission works on server client vs http.

Comment: I don't want user to gain permission only to the **files** inside of **core**

Comment: have you tested my htaccess?

Comment: ok i think you didn't explain very ok what you want to achieve. you deny access from user to look into your folders from  the browser or you want to deny access to view the source code.. ?